# Disable scollbar from NSCollecitonView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I'm new to MAC development. I have created NSCollectionview, which is Horizontally scrollable. I tried to disable horizontal scrollbar. But I could not hide. I applied following code to hide horizontal scroller.

```
let HScroller = self.colletionView.enclosingScrollView?.verticalScroller
```

HScroller?.isHidden = true

Thanks